# Component in flex to render the excel

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any components of flex that render the excel in flex?

I want to render the excel with excel functions, excel formatting, excel Formulas, etc. in flex. And also wants to perform actions on that excel row and column, like applying formulas, formatting text, insert function etc. in flex version 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-library for this. You would have to develop this by building on top of Flex's DataGrid. This is a huge project. You have to ask yourself if it is reasonable to embark on such a project, given that Flex will no longer work in any browser when Flash is retired in 2020.
In the javascript world you will find many options for 'Excel-like' grids.